# What is the equivalent to Flutter's pubspec.yaml in python

Tags: python, flutter

**SITUATION**: I started my coding journey in Flutter, where the pubspec.yaml file at the root of my project directory allows me to easily manage the external libraries / dependencies that my project uses.

**COMPLICATION**: I've recently started using python as well and am having a lot more trouble managing external packages. From what I can see, people seem to mainly do either of the following within a venv (both of which I consider way less easy & intuitive:

1. Install packages manually with pip
2. Use a requirements.txt file and then group-install packages manually with that

**QUESTION**: Is there an easier way to manage my external packages in python that is similar to Flutter's pubspec.yaml?

Comment: I think the closest would be requirements.txt created with `pip freeze > requirements.txt`, this is good enough if you use virtual environments where you only install what your script needs, if you use something like poetry then you can use the `pyproject.tom` file https://python-poetry.org/docs/pyproject/

Answer (score 0):

There is also an alternative to this, such as the [**pipfile**](https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/pipfile/) , which you can use it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).